# Joint CDF of $Z = X_1 + X_2 + X_3, Y = X_3$

Tags: distributions, self-study, joint-distribution

Given order statistics $X_1 < X_2 < X_3$ I am trying to find the Joint CDF of $Z = X_1 + X_2 + X_3, Y = X_3$. i.e. $P(Y \le y, Z \le t)$.

I am leaving out the specific distribution as I have already found the joint pdf $f(y,z).$ I introduced a new variable and then was able to integrate out that new variable to get $f(y,z)$

In the pdf, as should be clear from definition of $Z,Y$, there is a dependency. I get two cases.

What I get for the first case $Y \le Z \le 2Y$ and $0 \le Y$. I am a bit rusty on my multivariable calculus. I believe in this case it would be

$\displaystyle P(Y\le y, Z \le t) = \int_{x}^{2x} \int_0^x f(y,z)dydz$

Note: the othe case is somewhat similar except the bounds for $Z$ are $2Y \le Z < \infty$

So here $\displaystyle P(Y\le y, Z \le t) = \int_{2x}^{t} \int_0^x f(y,z)dydz$

I just want to make sure I am setting these double integrals up correctly. Integrate first wrt $y$ then wrt $z$ as $z$ is dependent upon $y$. It seems related to convolutions but not that same as when there is a sum of two random variables.

Note: $f(y,z)$ is itself piece-wise thus the reason for the two cases.

Comment: I have some confusion: the $y$ that you introduce in $P(Y\leq y, Z\leq t)$ does not seem to be showing up in your integral since the $dy$ shadows it. Probably $y$ should be incorporated into a limit of integration somewhere?